# Find list of available scopes for PayPal API

Tags: go, paypal

I am trying to use the new PayPal Payouts API. I want to get an access token that gives me the ability to make a query like this:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.payouts-batch/v1/

I can get an access token with the scope "TRANSACTION_DETAILS" like so:

```
scope := "TRANSACTION_DETAILS"
url := fmt.Sprintf("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token?scope=%s", scope)
reqBody := "grant_type=client_credentials"
reqBodyBuf := bytes.NewBuffer([]byte(reqBody))
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, reqBodyBuf)
```

but when I make a POST request to get the payouts:

```
url := fmt.Sprintf("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payouts")
file, err := ioutil.ReadFile("payout.json")
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer(file))
req.Header.Set("Authorization", fmt.Sprintf("Bearer %s", accessToken))
req.Header.Set("Accept", "application/json")
req.Header.Set("Accept-Language", "en_US")
client := &http.Client{}
resp, err := client.Do(req)
```

I get this error:

> {"name":"REQUIRED_SCOPE_MISSING","message":"Access token does not have
>   required
>   scope.","debug_id":"603c58d7fe693","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.payouts-batch/#errors","links":[]}

I have searched online for an hour to try to find a comprehensive list of scopes and the scopes that would apply to the above request to /v1/payments/payouts, but I can't find anything - does anyone know how I can find out what scope I need to make the request?

Comment: Have you enabled all the relevant checkboxes of permissions for the sandbox mode REST App of your ClientID in https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications ? Also make sure you aren't re-using the same `sender_batch_id` on any repeat requests, as that can cause errors

Comment: Looks like there's a list here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/nvp-soap-api/get-access-token/

Answer (score 2):

The scope you are looking for is `https://uri.paypal.com/payments/payouts`.

Here is a list of scopes I found online, but I don't believe the exhaustive list is published anywhere.

```
openid
address
email
phone
profile
https://uri.paypal.com/payments/payouts
https://uri.paypal.com/services/applications/webhooks
https://uri.paypal.com/services/disputes/read-buyer
https://uri.paypal.com/services/disputes/read-seller
https://uri.paypal.com/services/disputes/update-seller
https://uri.paypal.com/services/expresscheckout
https://uri.paypal.com/services/identity/activities
https://uri.paypal.com/services/identity/grantdelegation
https://uri.paypal.com/services/identity/proxyclient
https://uri.paypal.com/services/invoicing
https://uri.paypal.com/services/payments/payment/authcapture
https://uri.paypal.com/services/payments/realtimepayment
https://uri.paypal.com/services/payments/refund
https://uri.paypal.com/services/paypalattributes/business
https://uri.paypal.com/services/paypalhere
https://uri.paypal.com/services/subscriptions
https://uri.paypal.com/services/reporting/search/read
https://api-m.paypal.com/v1/payments/.*
https://api-m.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card
https://api-m.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card/.*
https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/.*
https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/refund
https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/.*/refund
https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card
https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card/.*
```

Comment: Where did you find these scopes? The invoice scope doesn't seem to propagate properly when I initiate the OAuth2 process. I also don't get an error if I input a scope that is invalid so there is no feedback other than the fact that the scope is not visible in the JWT